# script with no arguments should echo a message, but it doesn't

Tags: shell-script, arguments, parameter

I'm questioning why my script still does not run the condition when no argument is provided. I think it might be the ordering of my if statements but I'm not sure. Any advice? It doesn't seem to be a simple mistake like misplaced white spaces.

```
for param in "$@";
do

    if [[ -n $confirm ]]; #this is a getopts switch asking for confirmation like rm -i
    then
        #asks user whether to confirm deletion
        if [ $answer != [Yy]* ]];
        then
            continue #go to next param argument
        fi
    fi

    if [ -z "$param" ] #if no argument has been specied,
    then
         #print an error that additional operand is needed.

    elif [ -d ./$param ] #if a directory name is specified
    then
        if [[ -n $recursive]] #getops recursive switch, like rm -r
        then
            #recursively delete a directory
        fi
        #error message about deleting directory without -r switch
    elif [ ! -e ./$param ] 
    then
        #If not an existing file either then print error that there is no such file or directory
    elif [[ $param = "safe_rm" ]] || [[ $param = "safe_rm_res" ]]
    then
        #This prevents script from trying to delete itself or restore script
    fi


    if [[ -n $verbose ]] third and final getopts switch, similar to rm -v
    then
        #message confirming deletion
    fi
done
```

My code is about making a recycling bin, it is based off of the `rm` command where the scripts also has and uses switches the same way as `rm -i -v` and `-r`. The if statements above changes how I handle deletion depending on the arguments.The first if statement is about whether the argument is a directory. The second is whether it is a file, the third is whether it is empty, the fourth is whether the argument is itself (deleting itself)

Comment: "*script with no arguments should echo a message, but it doesnt*". No surprise it doesn't *echo* - there is no `echo` command anywhere.

Comment: that's not a valid `if` statement is it, where is the `then`

Comment: I've only provided the actual conditions as I thought the ordering of the conditions might be the problem. If there isn't I could try and add more code to it?

Comment: Yes please try to come up with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem

Comment: I hope the edit helps

Comment: It's neither complete nor verifiable. The fault might be further up the code. Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the problem as requested by @steeldriver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop being used to iterate over the arguments terminates and goes to its `done` statement when its condition is met (the end of the list).  When the script reaches the `for` loop with no arguments the start of the list is the same as the end, and the loop's condition is false.

In the original example the commands inside of the loop would have produced the incorrect result given an empty string.  If the variable "param" was empty the first case `[ -d ./$param ]` would match the current directory `./` before and the script reached the check for an empty string `[ -z "$param" ]`.

Comment: I tried moving the [ -z "$param" ] test to the top, but it still doesn't seem to work. If it matters, all the tests are in a giant for loop 
for param in "$@";
do

Comment: If no argument is specified then the `for` loop has nothing to iterate over and gets skipped over.

Comment: surely the for loop will just have one iteration?

Comment: It will check its condition at the start of the loop like a `while` loop, if this condition is not met then it will go to the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I moved the test outside the loop and it worked. I wonder why it worked on a different script and i noticed it didnt have a loop either